# How to show nullable decimal values without unnecessary zeros?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    ID INT,
    V DECIMAL(28, 10) NULL
)


INSERT INTO a(ID, V)
VALUES(1, 12.345)

INSERT INTO a(ID)
VALUES(2)
```

The desired output is like

```
╔════╤═══════╗
║ ID │ V     ║
╠════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ 12.35 ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │       ║
╚════╧═══════╝
```

But with this query, I got NULL for row 2:

```
SELECT ID, ROUND([V], 2) AS V
FROM a;

ID  V
1   12.3500000000
2   NULL
```

With this query I got unnecessary zeros for row 2:

```
SELECT ID, ROUND(ISNULL(CAST(V AS VARCHAR(50)), ''), 2) AS V
FROM a;

ID  V
1   12.35
2   0
```

Can anybody help please? Database is SQL Server 2005.

UPDATED:

This query will result in unwanted scale:

```
SELECT ID, ISNULL(CAST(ROUND(V, 2) AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AS V
FROM   a;

ID  V
1   12.3500000000
2
```

Comment: thanks for doing all the legwork on this one, thorough post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, because you have V as a number when you Round

```
select 1 union select ''
```

This leads to output

```
1
0
```

So, what you need to do is round `V` then convert to a string while keeping the rounding.  Easier said than done :

```
SELECT ID, case when v is null then '' else left(CAST(ROUND(V,2) AS VARCHAR(50)),charindex('.', CAST(ROUND(V,2) AS VARCHAR(50)))+2) end AS V
FROM a;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37439/20)

I just use some brute force string manipulation to find the decimal and round that way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `NULL` value as `NULL`, then simply remove the `ISNULL()`:

```
SELECT ID, ROUND(CAST(V AS VARCHAR(50)), 2) AS V
FROM a;
```

If you know the precision that you want, then I would suggest using either `STR()` or casting to the decimal with the specified precision.

Comment: gordon (thanks for all your great work here!!) he wants a zls rather than null in the output

Answer (score 0):

you should

1. ROUND() to 2 decimal places
2. then CAST() to string
3. follow by ISNULL() to convert NULL to empty string

query :

```
SELECT ID, ISNULL(CAST(ROUND(V, 2) AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AS V
FROM   a;
```

Comment: this doesn't round the number to 2 digits

Comment: then change `ROUND(V,2)` to `CONVERT(decimal(10,2), V)`